# Sharing 115 VAC ground and 28 volt DC ground

Tags: ac, dc, grounding

[image: Schematics]

I have been wondering if it makes sense to tie DC Power and AC Power ground like this.

Basically the AC return from an AC power supply is tied to the DC Power negative line as well.

Is there a good reason for doing it shown above?

Comment: How is the 28 V DC generated? Is your AC “ground” actually neutral? It’s not clear from your diagram.

Comment: in AC power, neutral line and ground line are two different things

Comment: @MooCow Seems dicey. Why would you want to do something like this?

Comment: 28 volts is generated by a separate power supply.

Comment: Also the AC is being powered via an AC power supply

Comment: @MooCow changing the wording from "neutral" to "AC return" doesn't change the fact that your proposal is against the National Electrical Code in the US and probably codes elsewhere. "neutral" and "AC return" mean the same thing.

Comment: I don't think National Electrical code applies to aircraft...

Comment: @MooCow no, the NEC does not apply to aircraft. Is your circuit in an aircraft? If so, such relevant information belongs in the question.

Comment: I can update the question but primarily yes.

Comment: "Ground" is an interesting concept in an aircraft. Do you mean "chassis" or "body"?

Comment: Chassis, I never have heard of the term body used before

Answer (score 1):

> Basically the neutral line is tied to the DC Power negative line as well.

### NO!

Do not connect the neutral of your AC mains to ground, except at the breaker box. To do so is a safety hazard, and is also against code in many countries.

If you are fortunate enough to have GFCI or RCD breakers, connecting the neutral and ground will almost certainly cause your breakers to trip as soon as something substantial on that mains circuit is powered up. Tripping the breakers is a **good** thing, but it will make your device unusable.